# Xpath - nodes have varying number of values

Tags: xml, r, xpath

Here is the structure:

```
<div>
<ul>
  <li>"asdffa"</li>
  <li><a href = "www.abc.com"> text </a> 
"asdfasdfasdfagh" 
<a href = "www.xyz.com"> asdf </a>
"uidhfbnkaer" </li>
<li>"oijh" <a href = "www.123.com"> jcb </a>
"sdfhwebwyh cxvyjbwer" </li>
```

I am new to XPath and have two tasks:

1. Grab all text under a certain set of nodes. I have done this with `/div//ul//li` so no problem there.
2. I need to grab the href URLs within each `<li>` - the problem is that some `<li>` have zero links, others have 1-2. I can grab all the links with `div//ul//li//a//@href`, but then I don't know which `<li>` they came from (I think).

Does anyone know how I could have XPath return the relative position of each `<li>` text, and then return the links with the relative position they fall under? Ultimately I want to bind them together in a dataframe in R. I don't need to know within a `li` which text falls below which link, I just want to concatenate all links.

E.g.

1. asdffa
2. asdfasdfasdfagh uidhfbnkaer   www.abc.com, www.xyz.com
3. oijh jcb sdfhwebwyh cxvyjbwer   www.123.com

Comment: I've fixed some significant formatting problems with your question, but you should [edit] and improve it further by (1) cleaning up your input XML example and (2) specifying clearly what result you require from XPath.   Keep in mind that XPath is for *selection*, not *transformation*; use XSLT for transformation.  Thanks.

Comment: I might try "//div/ul/li | //div/ul/li/a/@href"